# Unable to get result from $match with $and in pymongo

Tags: mongodb, match, aggregate, pymongo

I have mongodb query which I am trying to implement with pymongo.

I have the collection dictionaries as below:

```
{'_id': 0,
 'name': 'aimee Zank',
 'scores': [{'score': 10.463179736705023, 'type': 'exam'},
  {'score': 11.78273309957772, 'type': 'quiz'},
  {'score': 75.8740349954354, 'type': 'homework'}]}


{'_id': 1,
 'name': 'Tomas Jude',
 'scores': [{'score': 55.9736705023, 'type': 'exam'},
  {'score': 50.78273309957772, 'type': 'quiz'},
  {'score': 45.8740349954354, 'type': 'homework'}]}
```

I am trying to query for students with score higher than 40 in all three types (exam, quiz and homework). For this, I am using $match with $and in the aggregate. I am unable to get any result, with $or the condition works correctly.

```
agg_result=Collection.aggregate([
    {"$unwind" : "$scores" },
   {"$match": {"scores.score": {"$gt":40}}},
   { 
       "$match": {
           "$and" : [
                     {"scores.type": "exam"},
                     {"scores.type":"homework"}
                     ]
                  }
    },
   
   {
       "$group": {
           "_id" : "$_id",
           "name": {"$first": "$name"},
          "scores":{"$push" : "$scores"}
       }
   },
   
  {
      "$sort": {
          "_id" : 1
      }
  }

])
```

With $or, the result shows as,

```
{'_id': 0,
     'name': 'aimee Zank',
     'scores': [{'score': 75.8740349954354, 'type': 'homework'}]}

{'_id': 1,
     'name': 'Tomas Jude',
     'scores': [{'score': 55.9736705023, 'type': 'exam'},
      {'score': 45.8740349954354, 'type': 'homework'}]}
```

How to work around for $and?

Comment: you can use `$or` instead of `$and`. or you can use `$in` operator like `{ "scores.type": { "$in": ["exam", "homework"] } }`

Comment: @turivishal I want the output to be shown for both exam and homework, so I tried to use and. I tried with $in as shown below. But, it is not working. Is it wrong implementation?

`"$match": {
           "$and" : [
                     {"scores.type":  { "$in": ["exam", "homework"] }},
                     #{"scores.type":"quiz"}
                     ]
                  }`

Comment: @Sunag: you are matching sub-documents with score > 40 , causing the document : {'score': 10.463179736705023, 'type': 'exam'} to miss in the final result , but indeed as suggested by turvishal what you want to achieve can be done with $in or $or , but not with $and since you cannot have type:"exam" & type:"homework" at the same time in same subdocument ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may have made a mountain out of a molehill, but it was the first thing that came to mind (which means there's probably a better way). You can use `"$map"` to cycle through the `scores` array where we can check the `score` with the `type` and build the `pass` array.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    // create array of pass status
    "$set": {
      "pass": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$scores",
          "as": "score",
          "in": {
            "$switch": {
              "branches": [
                {
                  "case": { "$eq": [ "$$score.type", "exam" ] },
                  "then": { "exam": { "$gt": [ "$$score.score", 40 ] } }
                },
                {
                  "case": { "$eq": [ "$$score.type", "quiz" ] },
                  "then": { "quiz": { "$gt": [ "$$score.score", 40 ] } }
                },
                {
                  "case": { "$eq": [ "$$score.type", "homework" ] },
                  "then": { "homework": { "$gt": [ "$$score.score", 40 ] } }
                }
              ],
              "default": "$$score"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "pass.exam": true,
      "pass.quiz": true,
      "pass.homework": true
    }
  },
  // uncomment to "$unset" "pass"
  //  {
  //    "$unset": "pass"
  //  }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/n-nZrjzcjZM).

Comment: This solves the problem..!! The logic is good..!!